# DataAnnotation Presentation Working on IIS Express but Not Working on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC application, and controlling the presentation of the element properties using Data Annotations.  The result is fine on IIS Express directly from Visual studio, but when I deploy to the UAT Server the Annotations fail.

Code:

Edit.cshtml:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.GlobalizedElement)
```

Model:

```
public class GlobalizedElement
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ElementId { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "InternalDescription", ResourceType = typeof(EntityDataAnnotations))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EntityValidation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredInternalDescription")]
    public string InternalDescription { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "InterviewDescription", ResourceType = typeof(EntityDataAnnotations))]
    public string InterviewDescription { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [AllowHtml]
    [Display(Name = "ExternalDescription", ResourceType = typeof(EntityDataAnnotations))]
    public string ExternalDescription { get; set; }
}
```

The IIS Express presentation hides the hidden fields, and uses multiline text boxes.

The deployed IIS presentation shows all fields, and only single line text boxes.

I am using VS2013 on Windows 7 Ultimate, and deploying to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**Ricardo** - No there are no script elements on the form.  The problem seems to be in the rendering engine.  The page source from the IIS Express server is:

```
     <div class="editor-field">
                    <textarea class="text-box&#32;multi-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please&#32;enter&#32;a&#32;internal&#32;description" id="GlobalizedElement_InternalDescription" name="GlobalizedElement.InternalDescription">
                    </textarea> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.InternalDescription" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_InterviewDescription">Interview description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <textarea class="text-box&#32;multi-line" id="GlobalizedElement_InterviewDescription" name="GlobalizedElement.InterviewDescription">
                    </textarea> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.InterviewDescription" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_ExternalDescription">External description</label>
                </div>

For IIS it is: 

<div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_Id">Id</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The&#32;field&#32;Id&#32;must&#32;be&#32;a&#32;number." data-val-required="The&#32;Id&#32;field&#32;is&#32;required." id="GlobalizedElement_Id" name="GlobalizedElement.Id" type="number" value="0" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_ElementId">ElementId</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The&#32;field&#32;ElementId&#32;must&#32;be&#32;a&#32;number." data-val-required="The&#32;ElementId&#32;field&#32;is&#32;required." id="GlobalizedElement_ElementId" name="GlobalizedElement.ElementId" type="number" value="0" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.ElementId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_CultureCode">CultureCode</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" id="GlobalizedElement_CultureCode" name="GlobalizedElement.CultureCode" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.CultureCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_InternalDescription">InternalDescription</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" id="GlobalizedElement_InternalDescription" name="GlobalizedElement.InternalDescription" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.InternalDescription" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_InterviewDescription">InterviewDescription</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" id="GlobalizedElement_InterviewDescription" name="GlobalizedElement.InterviewDescription" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.InterviewDescription" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label for="GlobalizedElement_ExternalDescription">ExternalDescription</label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <input class="text-box&#32;single-line" id="GlobalizedElement_ExternalDescription" name="GlobalizedElement.ExternalDescription" type="text" value="" /> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="GlobalizedElement.ExternalDescription" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
```

Comment: did you check out for javascript errors when you browse from your server?

Comment: Ricardo - No there are no script elements on the form.  The problem seems to be in the rendering engine.  The page source from the IIS Exoress server is:

Comment: Ricardo more info above.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Trevor, it is looking you have different versions of Razor in your dev environment and server. Could you checkout your assembly versions between environments (System.Web.Mvc.dll)?